# PlayN: Auto reload/refresh Java application

Tags: java, playn

I see on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=F_sbusEUz5w#t=1462s (24:15) that the Java application can be auto reloaded by changing sources. But it doesn't work for me, I have to close and launch again the app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found it ! Mode debug on Eclipse works for me.

Comment: there are limitations on how well live reloading can work - if a method signature changes, it can't reload, and also, reloading static fields might not work (sometimes). If you are willing to pay money, you can try java rebel (http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) which can handle all of it.